# Pass string variable as query parameter to LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I am attempting to pass a string variable via a POST request in my MVC controller into a LINQ query. I have tried a number of variations on the dynamic LINQ examples(which seems to be the primary recommended method.

#### EXPECTED RESULT

> An IEnumerable array which contains results based on specified SiteID displayed in an ng-repeat.

#### NON-DYNAMIC-LINQ QUERY

```
public IEnumerable<SpecialsViewModel> GetAllSpecialsBySiteID(string siteID)
{
    var query = (from s in _calcContext.Specials
    where s.SiteID == siteID
    select new SpecialsViewModel
    {
        ID = s.ID,
        SiteID = s.SiteID,
        Title = s.Title,
        Description = s.Description,
        Price = s.Price,
        Position = s.Position,
        EffectiveDate = s.EffectiveDate,
        CreationDate = s.CreationDate,
        Status = s.Status,
        LastUpdated = s.LastUpdated
    }).ToList();

    return query;
}
```

> #### RESULT
>
> No results returned.

#### DYNAMIC LINQ QUERY

```
public IEnumerable<SpecialsViewModel> GetAllSpecialsBySiteID(string siteID)
{ 
    var query = (from s in _calcContext.Specials
    select new SpecialsViewModel
    {
        ID = s.ID,
        SiteID = s.SiteID,
        Title = s.Title,
        Description = s.Description,
        Price = s.Price,
        Position = s.Position,
        EffectiveDate = s.EffectiveDate,
        CreationDate = s.CreationDate,
        Status = s.Status,
        LastUpdated = s.LastUpdated
    });

    query = query.Where("SiteID=@0", siteID);

    return query;
}
```

> #### RESULT
>
> No results returned.

Comment: Does it return any result if you remove ***where*** clause?

Comment: Can you confirm that when selecting this in the database with that `where` any records return?

Comment: Yes I can confirm that when I provide a two character string in a database query that it returns results as expected and also returns the entire result set if I leave out the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

If both of your linq queries fail to return results, I suspect the value you are passing in is not what you expect. Try hardcoding a value for siteID to a known good value and see if that works. (I prefer the first query, but both are fine)

Comment: I can see the value being posted in the browser developer tools however when I view the value at the breakpoint for the function, it's null.

Comment: That's your problem then, not the linq

Comment: That is why I was trying to re-write the linq in order for it to work properly. I've also tried adding the property to the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

try to cast `siteID` to int and pass to where clause
eg:   `where s.SiteID == (int32?)siteID`

Comment: The siteID is a 2-character length value so can't be an int.